# No error in code. But while launching the app says, Unfortunately app has stopped

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I am developed simple android application including some simple adding calculation function.  After the Run emulator display that kind error. More time wasted to find that error in android application. No error in code. But while launching the app says, Unfortunately app has stopped.

[Error- Screen Shot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wEy7R.png)

My Code as Follows

*activity_main.xml*

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity"
    tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="81dp">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView_answer"
        android:layout_width="100dp"
        android:layout_height="25dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="130dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="300dp"
        android:text="0"
        android:textSize="20dp"
        android:textStyle="bold" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView_first_no"
        android:layout_width="150dp"
        android:layout_height="25dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="50dp"
        android:text="First number"
        android:textSize="20dp" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView_second_no"
        android:layout_width="150dp"
        android:layout_height="25dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="100dp"
        android:text="Second number"
        android:textSize="20dp" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/editText_first_no"
        android:layout_width="150dp"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="200dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="40dp"
        android:inputType="number"
        tools:ignore="MissingConstraints" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/editText_second_no"
        android:layout_width="150dp"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="200dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="90dp"
        android:inputType="number"
        tools:ignore="MissingConstraints" />


</RelativeLayout>
```

*MainActivity.java*

```
package com.example.marks;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    EditText number1;
    EditText number2;
    Button Add_button;
    TextView result;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        number1 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText_first_no);
        number2 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText_second_no);
        result = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView_answer);

        Add_button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            public void onClick(View v) {

                double num1 = Double.parseDouble(number1.getText().toString());
                double num2 = Double.parseDouble(number2.getText().toString());

                double sum = num1 + num2;

                result.setText(Double.toString(sum));
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: What does logcat say?

Comment: @federico-klez-culloca No anything..

Comment: Can't be. There will be an exception in logcat.

Comment: @Sergey Glotov nothing says logcat. sure. but xml file view some warnings.

Comment: You're just missing those logs, then, somehow, because you were at least getting a `NullPointerException` at some point, if not still.

Comment: @Mike M thank you. I found that

Answer (score 3):

Where the button (Add_button) on your xml file.
The error is because the button is not defined yet.

Comment: after button was added. but error is same

Comment: You should alsow initialize it by add_button =findviewbyid...

Comment: <Button android:id="@+id/submit"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Submit"/>

Button Add_button = findViewById(R.id.submit);